Unity Android Plugin Not Checking Res Directory
I am adding an android plugin as a .aar to Assets/Plugins/Android. The build fails with the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\30b88d8670c3d8023780bd68d95f322d\transformed\jetified-emu-android-storage-bridge-debug\res\layout\activity_main.xml:13: error: attribute navGraph (aka com.io.my.Package:navGraph) not found.

The .aar plugin works perfectly when I use it outside of Unity in a standalone Android project. I verified that the .aar file does include the nav_graph.xml in its res/navigation/ directory, and the activity_main.xml references it like this:
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

Additional Details:

Unity version: 2023.2.3f1
compileSdkVersion: 34
targetSdkVersion: 34
minSdkVersion: 31
The .aar is placed in the Assets/Plugins/Android directory.

What could cause Unity to fail to use the bundled resources in the .aar and look in the Gradle cache instead? How can I ensure Unity resolves these resources correctly?

This question is similar to: AAPT: error: '#ffffff' is incompatible with attribute drawable (attr) reference. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
